# Attaching [SOLVED] to title of questions with accepted answers

Tags: discussion, question-titles

Is it good practice to attach [SOLVED] to a solved question's title? I know this helps a lot when searching forums, but in a SO environment there is a visual clue for solved questions.

Comment: Please never do this and if you see it, remove it.

Comment: But don't remove just that! Check for other improvements that could be done to the post ;)

Comment: I always do, but thanks for pointing it out. ;) Anyway, is there a default resolution/convention I can link to when commenting to the OP about the reason for the edit?

Comment: Using the title for indicating a property of the question is semantically incorrect. *Just sayin'...*

Comment: It's just a question.. why the downvotes?

Comment: @NathanOsman, could you help me rephrase the question, then?

Comment: @SalmanPK, beats me. :-/

Answer (score 18):

Marking an answer as accepted is the signal that the question is solved. [We are not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums), and there are mechanisms to look for questions that have answers and are accepted answers:

- [`answers:3`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=answers:3) questions that have 3 or more answers.
- [`answers:0`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=answers:0) questions that have no answers.
- [`isaccepted:yes`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=isaccepted:yes) answers marked as accepted.
- [`hasaccepted:no`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=hasaccepted:no) questions that don't have accepted answers.

If someone's answer solved your question, [mark it as accepted](http://www.askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) or upvote it. Please, don't edit questions to add `[SOLVED]` to the title. If you see a question that has the answer embedded in the question, either comment to the author that he could answer his own question, or edit the question and add the answer yourself.

Related questions about this:

- [Detect edits to add [SOLVED] or [RESOLVED] to the title and direct the user to add an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a)
- [Is it OK to add [Solved] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)
- [Putting [SOLVED] in the title of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question)