# Sorting out SOLVED for good

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/630354/178596) whilst rapidly browsing earlier - the OP added "SOLVED: " to the title, but did add vaguely how they got the answer but did not accept it.

Searching for other people doing similar things returns LOADs of questions:

[image: 18801 results]

And [filtering it down a bit returns 4713 questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=solved+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano) - but [doing the same filtered search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=solved+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano) on stackoverflow returns 147500 (though that is out of the near 10million they have there).

A [previous meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/178596) mentions solutions and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a) - would it be a good idea to kick the idea awake again (if possible)? A warning could be added and make things nice and tidy etc... Either that or quizzing users after the intial SE site tour when they first sign up....

EDIT: [A reason for users in a hurry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630354/game-crashes-while-running-with-wine/630386?noredirect=1#comment897676_630386) doing the SOLVED thing:
[image: I tried to use the tick box but the system said it must pass 3 days before I can accept my own answer]

So perhaps reducing the wait time, or using reminders (probably in use already... even with just comments) etc could help

ANOTHER EDIT: lol, realised the search was doing the body of the post as well - [this](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3Asolved+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano) search returns the ones with solved in the title, returning a more manageable 58, some of which are not what we are looking for anyway :D

YET ANOTHER EDIT: oh great, found '[fixed](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3A[fixed]+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano)' is a less popular version of solved....

Comment: That wait time is for users who answer their own questions. It used to be 2 days though, not three. I don't know why the period is this long though. On Ask Ubuntu, more than a day for a question means the question is gone, unless someone had bookmarked it.

Comment: @Dan more than a day for a question certainly does not mean it's gone. It may be unanswered, answered, or in review.

Comment: @eldergeek But what are the chances of a question getting new answers after a day?

Comment: @Dan Better than you might think. There are even related badges awarded.

Comment: @Dan: like people who look through interesting questions once/day or week through e-mail notifications...

Comment: Or people like me who only answer questions when they get on to get a question answered...

Comment: Related: [Suggest to post answer / accept one when changing title to “Solved”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294924/1983854)

Answer (score 11):

That is behavior from Ubuntu Forums.  This is not Ubuntu Forums.  Did somebody fail to shift paradigms and thereby pop the clutch?

Comment: Well that's the function on must forums, that's one of the problems with this unique type of Forums....

Answer (score 3):

Good catch!  I'm going through them now and closing some of them as "Problem went away all by its own"...  (expect the close queue to grow by a whatever my max/day Close Votes are)

On the other hand: I also saw some [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313905/laptop-overheating-on-ubuntu-12-04-solved-in-strange-way) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411128/solved-ssh-connection-refused-from-windows-but-not-from-linux) that I will be editing and answering myself and then flagging for moderator attention to get "my" answers converted to a Community Wiki...

Comment: I thought of closing/answering them all (and did one or two myself), it just takes flipping ages (only 4700 give to take a few, with 50 close votes a day), so a system to sort it out would help :) Also means finding things like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/600164/178596) to make us cringe...

Comment: :D :D :D  Cringe or LOL!  Answer edited...

Comment: LOL :)  Oh and you can make community wiki posts by checking the box beneath the answer box, see my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/630956/178596) on the first one you referenced -  you don't need to ask the mods

Comment: Oops!  I missed that! Now going to continue working the queue...

Comment: Seems like I've done a good job: the only questions on the last couple of pages were "How do I solve?" type questions... On to the VTC queue!  :P

Comment: Apart from ones that need to close voted, I think for now this is done - I dunno which answer to pick so I may just add SOLVED: to the title...

Comment: :D Answer your own question, then!